Error with ffmpeg_kit_flutter_https_gpl in Flutter: "Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file"
I'm using the render: ^0.0.8 library in my Flutter project. I've added this dependency to my pubspec.yaml file. However, whenever I run my project, I encounter the following error:
A problem occurred configuring project ':ffmpeg_kit_flutter_https_gpl'.

Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.

Note: I have already specified the namespace in my build.gradle file, but the error persists.
Here is my project information:
android {
    namespace = "com.example.lyrics_app"
    compileSdk = 34
    ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"

Gradle version:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.12-all.zip

Please help me to fix the above error. Thanks in advance!

The issue seems to be with the Render package, as it uses an older version of Gradle, which is incompatible with the Gradle version specified in your project (distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.12-all.zip).
To resolve this, follow these steps:

Download the Render Package: Download the Render package directly.

Add Render to Your Project: Create a new folder in your project
(e.g., packages), and paste the downloaded Render package inside
this folder.

Upgrade Dependencies: In the pubspec.yaml of the Render package, try
upgrading the version of the ffmpeg_kit_flutter_https_gpl plugin to
the latest version.


This should update the plugin and add the necessary namespace.
By updating the namespace in the ffmpeg_kit_flutter_https_gpl plugin, this should help resolve the issue you're facing.
If this doesn’t work:

You might have to update the Gradle version used by the Render
package by downloading it and manually upgrading the Gradle version
along with any dependencies the package is using.
Alternatively, if you’re comfortable, you could downgrade the Gradle
version in your Android Studio to match the version expected by the
Render plugin, although this approach might be a bit more complex.

